# Java keyStore does not properly store X509 certificate chains

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, bouncycastle

I'm using the following code to generate a certificate chain with a root certificate, an intermediate and an end certificate:

**TestCertificates.java**

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AuthorityKeyIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v1CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PrivateKeyFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.X509KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.bc.BcRSAContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500PrivateCredential;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;


public class TestX509Certificates {

    private static final int VALIDITY_PERIOD = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // one week
    private static final int RSA_SEC_PARAM = 1024;
    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    private static final String X509_CERTIFICATE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA256WITHRSAENCRYPTION";
    private static final String ROOT_ALIAS = "root";
    private static final String INTERMEDIATE_ALIAS = "intermediate";
    private static final String END_ENTITY_ALIAS = "end";

    public static KeyPair generateRSAKeyPair()
            throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

        kpGen.initialize(RSA_SEC_PARAM, random);

        return kpGen.generateKeyPair();
    }

    /**
     * Generate a sample V1 certificate to use as a CA root certificate
     */
    public static X509Certificate generateRootCert(KeyPair pair) throws Exception {

        // Pick the public-key signature algorithm to sign certificates. We are using RSA
        AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(X509_CERTIFICATE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        // Pick the algorithm to perform the hashing on the information to be signed. We
        // sign the resulting hash
        AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
        // Retrieve the private key which is used to sign the certificate
        AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKeyAsymKeyParam = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
        // Retrieve the pulic key information used by the subject to verify
        // the signature
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo subPubKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
        ContentSigner sigGen = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(privateKeyAsymKeyParam);
        // Define the validity period. The certificate may expire before the
        // end date but not after.
        Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date endDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_PERIOD);
        X500Name name = new X500Name("CN=Root");
        // Create unique serial number for the certificate (need to check if it
        // it's actually unique)
        BigInteger serialNum = BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextLong());
        // Generate the actual certificate
        X509v1CertificateBuilder certGen = new X509v1CertificateBuilder(name, serialNum, startDate, endDate, name, subPubKeyInfo);
        // Sign it
        X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = certGen.build(sigGen);

        return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certificateHolder);

    }

    /**
     * Generate a sample V3 certificate to use as an intermediate CA certificate
     */
    public static X509Certificate generateIntermediateCert(PublicKey intKey, PrivateKey caKey, X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {

        ASN1Sequence seq = null;

        seq = (ASN1Sequence) new ASN1InputStream(intKey.getEncoded()).readObject();
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo parentPubKeyInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(seq);
        // Define the validity period. The certificate may expire before the
        // end date but not after.
        Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date endDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_PERIOD);
        ContentSigner signer = null;

        signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(X509_CERTIFICATE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).build(caKey);

        // Create unique serial number for the certificate (need to check if it
        // it's actually unique)
        BigInteger serialNum = BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextLong());
        X509v3CertificateBuilder certGen = null;

        certGen = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
                caCert,
                serialNum,
                startDate,
                endDate,
                new X500Principal("CN=Intermediate Certificate"),
                intKey)
                .addExtension(
                        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.35"),
                        false,
                        new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(parentPubKeyInfo))
                .addExtension(
                        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.19"),
                        false,
                        new BasicConstraints(false)) // true if it is allowed to sign other certs
                .addExtension(
                        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.15"),
                        true,
                        new X509KeyUsage(
                                X509KeyUsage.digitalSignature |
                                        X509KeyUsage.nonRepudiation |
                                        X509KeyUsage.keyEncipherment |
                                        X509KeyUsage.dataEncipherment));

        // Build/sign the certificate.
        X509CertificateHolder certHolder = certGen.build(signer);
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);

        return cert;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a sample V3 certificate to use as an end entity certificate
     */
    public static X509Certificate generateEndEntityCert(PublicKey entityKey, PrivateKey caKey, X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
        ASN1Sequence seq = null;
        seq = (ASN1Sequence) new ASN1InputStream(entityKey.getEncoded()).readObject();
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo parentPubKeyInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(seq);
        // Define the validity period. The certificate may expire before the
        // end date but not after.
        Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date endDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_PERIOD);
        ContentSigner signer = null;

        signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(X509_CERTIFICATE_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).build(caKey);

        // Create unique serial number for the certificate (need to check if it
        // it's actually unique)
        BigInteger serialNum = BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextLong());

        X509v3CertificateBuilder certGen = null;

        certGen = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
                caCert,
                serialNum,
                startDate,
                endDate,
                new X500Principal("CN=End Certificate"),
                entityKey)
                .addExtension(
                        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.35"),
                        false,
                        new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(parentPubKeyInfo))
                .addExtension(
                        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.19"),
                        false,
                        new BasicConstraints(false)) // true if it is allowed to sign other certs
                .addExtension(
                        new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("2.5.29.15"),
                        true,
                        new X509KeyUsage(
                                X509KeyUsage.digitalSignature |
                                        X509KeyUsage.nonRepudiation |
                                        X509KeyUsage.keyEncipherment |
                                        X509KeyUsage.keyCertSign |
                                        X509KeyUsage.cRLSign |
                                        X509KeyUsage.dataEncipherment));


        // Build/sign the certificate.
        X509CertificateHolder certHolder = certGen.build(signer);
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);

        return cert;
    }

    /**
     * Generate a X500PrivateCredential for the root entity.
     */
    public static X500PrivateCredential createRootCredential() throws Exception {
        KeyPair rootPair = null;

        rootPair = generateRSAKeyPair();

        X509Certificate rootCert = generateRootCert(rootPair);

        return new X500PrivateCredential(rootCert, rootPair.getPrivate(), ROOT_ALIAS);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a X500PrivateCredential for the intermediate entity.
     */
    public static X500PrivateCredential createIntermediateCredential(
            PrivateKey caKey,
            X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
        KeyPair interPair = null;

        interPair = generateRSAKeyPair();

        X509Certificate interCert = generateIntermediateCert(interPair.getPublic(), caKey, caCert);

        return new X500PrivateCredential(interCert, interPair.getPrivate(), INTERMEDIATE_ALIAS);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a X500PrivateCredential for the end entity.
     */
    public static X500PrivateCredential createEndEntityCredential(
            PrivateKey caKey,
            X509Certificate caCert) throws Exception {
        KeyPair endPair = null;

        endPair = generateRSAKeyPair();

        X509Certificate endCert = generateEndEntityCert(endPair.getPublic(), caKey, caCert);

        return new X500PrivateCredential(endCert, endPair.getPrivate(), END_ENTITY_ALIAS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Retrieve root, intermediate and end entity credentials
        X500PrivateCredential rootCredential = createRootCredential();
        X500PrivateCredential interCredential = createIntermediateCredential(rootCredential.getPrivateKey(), rootCredential.getCertificate());
        X500PrivateCredential endCredential = createEndEntityCredential(interCredential.getPrivateKey(), interCredential.getCertificate());

        // client credentials
        KeyStore keyStore = null;

        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setKeyEntry("client", endCredential.getPrivateKey(), "clientPassword".toCharArray(),
                new Certificate[]{endCredential.getCertificate(), interCredential.getCertificate(), rootCredential.getCertificate()});
        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("client.p12"), "clientPassword".toCharArray());

        // trust store for client
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        keyStore.load(null, null);

        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("trust", rootCredential.getCertificate());

        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("trust.jks"), "trustPassword".toCharArray());

        // server credentials
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        keyStore.load(null, null);

        keyStore.setKeyEntry("server", rootCredential.getPrivateKey(), "serverPassword".toCharArray(),
                new Certificate[]{rootCredential.getCertificate()});

        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("server.jks"), "serverPassword".toCharArray());
    }
}
```

The certificates are generated (they are present in memory and all fields appear to be valid) and written to the key store **client.p12**.

However, when viewing the contents of the file only a single entry is present (there is no intermediate or end certificate):

```
$ keytool -list -keystore client.p12 -storepass clientPassword -storetype PKCS12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

client, Nov 8, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): B9:0D:E9:99:64:9F:49:66:3A:F6:3F:19:A7:94:59:F9:38:B8:5B:29
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207378/saving-certificate-chain-in-a-pkcs12-keystore) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321557/can-not-get-key-from-keystore) question it appears that certificate ordering is important (end certificate -> intermediate certificate -> root certificate in my case) as well as the issuer of the certificate.

But is this the case in the code above?

**Edit:**

Adding the **-v** parameter while listing the client key store gives the following output:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore client.p12 -storepass clientPassword -v -storetype PKCS12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: client
Creation date: Nov 8, 2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=End Certificate
Issuer: CN=Intermediate Certificate
Serial number: -a5e7a9573956899
Valid from: Sun Nov 08 19:07:07 EET 2015 until: Sun Nov 15 19:07:07 EET 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  36:2A:E5:33:EC:41:A3:74:6D:38:4E:8E:71:30:E1:42
         SHA1: 6E:D6:D8:E6:9A:A7:41:68:0B:F9:86:E9:B5:2A:E2:A3:D6:08:D8:78
         SHA256: 01:1A:93:42:5C:AF:B2:03:EA:3C:AD:B9:9C:DA:AF:27:68:E0:0D:B4:7C:3C:34:56:9A:68:2C:B8:01:C6:89:79
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: D4 44 E3 F2 A9 87 0A 86   D6 19 4D B2 BF 25 C8 DB  .D........M..%..
0010: 8A 15 96 86                                        ....
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

**Edit #1:**

I have created the keystore using:

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
```

and got the following output:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore client.p12 -storepass clientPassword -v -storetype PKCS12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: client
Creation date: Nov 9, 2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 3
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=End Certificate
Issuer: CN=Intermediate Certificate
Serial number: 40f960450ce16070
Valid from: Mon Nov 09 12:08:34 EET 2015 until: Mon Nov 16 12:08:34 EET 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  2C:1F:97:91:B9:33:D3:F4:4F:89:AA:13:43:53:F5:8A
         SHA1: 41:83:C7:57:CE:B8:BC:DC:AC:E1:58:20:27:9E:05:CC:F2:F0:37:6C
         SHA256: 58:57:EA:83:F7:66:45:80:EF:0E:39:8D:60:9C:C4:C8:CF:7A:74:06:07:DE:37:E0:DF:5F:0C:5C:D6:D3:0D:AC
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 1E 5E A8 36 64 31 32 5B   83 9F CF 9F F3 5F F0 17  .^.6d12[....._..
0010: EF 83 12 E5                                        ....
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=Intermediate Certificate
Issuer: CN=Root
Serial number: 6d5f5d9bb7b110df
Valid from: Mon Nov 09 12:08:34 EET 2015 until: Mon Nov 16 12:08:34 EET 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  0A:F1:DD:AC:15:3C:90:8F:A5:BA:72:B9:40:FB:1E:D2
         SHA1: 78:DD:64:37:8F:94:F4:A1:F1:5E:80:70:89:18:0A:F4:6B:07:F8:3C
         SHA256: DF:04:BB:DD:72:85:E0:CB:83:C6:73:E0:7D:F5:F3:E9:54:4E:D1:32:8C:74:A2:31:AE:BF:7A:FD:FE:29:D3:7D
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 39 C5 42 A1 3D 0F B9 5F   C7 EA 32 9C 18 03 63 3D  9.B.=.._..2...c=
0010: 65 0F 30 22                                        e.0"
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

Certificate[3]:
Owner: CN=Root
Issuer: CN=Root
Serial number: 2c8b7a0f9a68a4d1
Valid from: Mon Nov 09 12:08:34 EET 2015 until: Mon Nov 16 12:08:34 EET 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  37:29:09:F2:E5:98:E1:EC:86:35:4E:A5:7F:54:06:70
         SHA1: 59:97:7E:3B:7B:5B:C5:A4:CA:17:92:24:60:EF:CE:4E:34:9D:4D:4A
         SHA256: B1:7B:20:EA:09:8E:72:3A:BC:59:54:9C:7B:78:0C:D7:45:D0:3C:90:AB:81:69:78:75:3E:B9:D1:CA:01:6B:D9
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

The certificates are being written but the issuer and subject fields are not valid.

**Edit #2:**

I have created a [git repository](https://github.com/Sebi1313/TestX509Certificates):

```
git clone https://github.com/Sebi1313/TestX509Certificates.git
```

Comment: Try the list command with the -v option.

Comment: @EJP I've added the output. I find it strange that the second output has an undefined CA? How come? It appears that only the end certificate is added.

Comment: Very strange. Try it with `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")`, i.e. using the Sun provider. NB You should generate another key pair and certificate for the server, rather than using the root.

Comment: @EJP I've changed the instance to "PKCS12" and got the output in the edited question. Why doesn't the "BC" instance store but one certificate?

Comment: Don't ask me. Ask them.